# Tengo un error SQL en WHERE id_usuario = NULL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estoy intentando generar una actualización en un CRUD, pero me marca este error y no me permite actualizar los nuevos datos.

Ya busque en otros lugares y no hay algo en específico:

> Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE id_usuario = NULL'

Anexo el código que estoy utilizando donde me aparece el error:

```
<?php 


//print_r($_POST);
  if (!isset($_POST['oculto_usuario2'])) {
    header('Location: tabla_usuario.php');
  }

  include 'conexion.php';
  $id2 = $_POST['id2'];
  $nom2=$_POST['txtNomina1'];
  $usserr2=$_POST['txtUsuario1'];
  $mail2=$_POST['txtCorreo1'];
  $puestoP2=$_POST['txtPuesto1'];
  $depar2=$_POST['txtDepartamento1'];
  $sucur2=$_POST['txtSucursal1'];
  $sUsuario2=$_POST['txtEstatusUsuario1'];

  $sentencia = $bd->prepare("UPDATE employees SET nomina = ?, nomUsuario = ?, correo = ?, 
                        puesto = ?, departamento = ?, sucursal = ?, estatus_usr = ?, WHERE id_usuario = ?;");
 $resultado = $sentencia->execute([$nom2,$usserr2,$mail2,$puestoP2,$depar2, $sucur2, $sUsuario2, $id2]);

  if ($resultado === TRUE) {
    header('Location: tabla_usuario.php');
  }else{
    echo "Error";
  }
?>
```

Éste es el código del formulario del `UPDATE`:

```
<?php  
  session_start();
  if (!isset($_GET['id'])) {
    header('Location: update_usuario.php');
  }

    include 'conexion.php';
    $id = $_GET['id'];

    $sentencia = $bd->prepare("SELECT * FROM employees WHERE id_usuario = ?;");
    $sentencia->execute([$id]);
    $persona = $sentencia->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    //print_r($persona);
?>
<?php
  require_once "Vistas/psuperior.php";
?>
<div>
<main role="main" class="col-md-9 ml-sm-auto col-lg-10 px-md-4">
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap align-items-center pt-3 pb-2 mb-3 border-bottom">
        <h1 class="h2">Edición de Usuario</h1>
      </div>

      <form action="actualizar_usuario.php" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="formGroupExampleInput">Nomina</label>
    <input name="txtNomina1" type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="Ingrese Número de Nomina" value="<?php echo $persona->nomina; ?>">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Nombre del Usuario: </label>
    <input name="txtUsuario1" type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput2" placeholder="Ingrese el Nombre del Usuario" value="<?php echo $persona->nomUsuario;  ?>">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Correo:</label>
    <input name="txtCorreo1" type="email" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput2" placeholder="Ingrese el Correo del Usuario" value="<?php echo $persona->correo; ?>">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Puesto:</label>
    <input name="txtPuesto1" type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput2" placeholder="Ingrese el Puesto del Usuario" value="<?php echo $persona->puesto;  ?>">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Departamento:</label>
    <input name="txtDepartamento1" type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput2" placeholder="Ingrese el Departamento del Usuario" value="<?php echo $persona->departamento;  ?>">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Sucursal:</label>
    <input name="txtSucursal1" type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput2" placeholder="Ingrese la Sucursal del Usuario" value="<?php echo $persona->sucursal;  ?>">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
  <label for="slctEstatusUsuario">Estatus:</label>
    <select name="txtEstatusUsuario1" class="form-control">
    <option value="Activo" selected disabled>Selecciona una Opción</option> 
    <option value="Activo">Activo</option>
    <option value="Baja">Baja</option>
    </select>
  </div>
<br><br>

<div class="form-group">
<input type="hidden" name="oculto_usuario2" value="1";>
</div>
<label for="IDusuarios">ID Usuario:</label>
<input name="id2" disabled value="<?php echo $persona->id_usuario; ?>">

  <div class="form-group">
  <center>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success">Actualizar Usuario <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-save"><path d="M19 21H5a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V5a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h11l5 5v11a2 2 0 0 1-2 2z"></path><polyline points="17 21 17 13 7 13 7 21"></polyline><polyline points="7 3 7 8 15 8"></polyline></svg></button>
  </center>  
</div>
</form>

    </main>

</div>

<?php
  require_once "Vistas/pinferior.php";
?>
```

Agradezco cualquier ayuda.

Comment: Parece que `$id2` vale `null` porque en realidad la variable `$_POST['id2']` no está definida o trae desde el HTML es valor porque es lo que contiene `$persona->id_usuario`. ¿Podrías comprobarlo viendo el código HTML generado?. Entonces, la comprobación tiene una sintaxis incorrecta porque la correcta sería usando la función [`ISNULL()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_isnull) de la siguiente manera: `WHERE ISNULL(id_usuario)`.

Comment: ¡Gracias! Ya se corrigió el error

Comment: Me alegra saberlo. ¿Cómo lo arreglaste? ¿Era el valor generado en el formulario? Por cierto, para evitar que tu código sea vulnerable a XSS deberías acostumbrarte a usar `value="<?= htmlspecialchars($persona->id_usuario) ?>"`. Cualquier salida al navegador debería ser saneada para que unas comillas o una entidad HTML te rompa el diseño y/o tenga la posibilidad de inyectarte código malicioso en la página si ese contenido no está bajo tu control.

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias por la recomendación, hice lo que me recomendaste, también hice una actualización a la declaración de SQL ya que no hacia el UPDATE